# c# 9.0 records - reflection and generic constraints

Tags: c#, c#-9.0, record-classes

Two questions regarding the new records feature :

1. How do I recognize a record using reflection ?  looking [here][1] maybe there
   is a way to detect the `EqualityContract` but I am not sure if that is the way to go ?
2. Is it possible to have a generic constraint that a generic type is a record ? that is if it is possible to indicate that type parameter T must be a record class using a constraint ?

Comment: Any pseudocode to help understand the problem?

Comment: What's not clear ?

Comment: Why are you asking this? First of all, a record is still a class. As for #2, what do you mean? Whether you can specify that T is a record? It's just a class, so probably no

Comment: I'm also unclear what the problem is you are trying to solve, but my first thought while reading your story was: Why doesn't he just use interfaces?

Comment: ©kofifus Currently there is an active discussion about this topic at [charplang's github under a Champion Record](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/39) From [this comment](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/39#issuecomment-680342093) you can read that there is an intent to do not be able to tell that a class is a record type.  In C# 10 "  there won't be a meaningful semantic difference between a record and a class"

Comment: Just FYI, there is a recently opened issue [#4121](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/4121) to determine whether a type is a record

Comment: I think it's a great question even if the answer is "You can't."  I was just wondering something related: Is there ever a time one _shouldn't_ use a record instead of a class?  The answers here seem to apply to that question as well: You can't tell the difference, so the only time you should stick with a class, I suppose, is if one of the built-in features of a record (such as member equality) conflicts with your intentions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I recognize a record using reflection ?

As pointed out [here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/39#issuecomment-680312194) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/3732#issuecomment-664142303)

> There is not only not an official way to do this, it is explicitly against the design of the feature. The intent for records is that, hopefully with C# 10, we'll get to a point where making a class a record is purely a convenience choice, and that every other part of the feature will be achievable through some form of syntax. It should not be a breaking change to change a type from a record to a class, and we even imagine that an IDE refactoring could automatically move a type to and from record syntax without clients noticing. For C# 9 there are some places where we didn't quite achieve this, but that's the goal.

Despite the above there are still scenarios where checking for record us useful. Some hackish ways to detect records which work ATM are:

1. check if there is an `EqualityContract` property with the `CompilerGenerated` attribute

```
isRecord = ((TypeInfo)t).DeclaredProperties.Where(x => x.Name == "EqualityContract").FirstOrDefault()?.GetMethod?.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute)) is object;
```

2. check for `<Clone>$` member as pointed out by @Yair Halberstadt

```
isRecord = t.GetMethod("<Clone>$") is object;
```

or a combination of both

> Is it possible to have a generic constraint that a generic type is a record ?

No

Comment: Looking for `<Clone>$` is how MVC binding detects that records need to be constructed. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/Metadata/DefaultBindingMetadataProvider.cs#L101

Answer (score 18):

As mentioned by everyone else, it's not possible to write

```
private void MyFunc<T>(T t) where T : record {...}
```

You can however create a record which you then have every record type you create inherit from. This will pretty much achieve what you are asking, although, I don't know how I feel about it...

```
public abstract record RecordMarker;
public record MyRecord : RecordMarker;
public void MyFunc<T>(T t) where T : RecordMarker
{
}
```

With this you can only pass record types in since classes cannot inherit from records.

```
MyFunc(new MyRecord()); // Works
MyFunc(new MyClass());  // Compiler Error
```

Comment: This is actually excellent. I want to point out the following works:
public abstract record Message;
public record TestMessage(string Msg, double Val) : Message;
var m = TestMessage("msg", 5d);
Still having that single line record definition really sold this method to me. Other than type constraints not saying record instead of Message (or whatever) and therefore being a bit less readable, there are no downsides.

Comment: Doesn't work in VisualStudio 17.5.2 targeting net 6.  Tried with base record being abstract record and record.  Both give the same error message:

"There is no implicit reference conversion from 'T' to '<namespace>.<MyBaseRecord>'"

Answer (score 15):

> 1. How do I recognize a record using reflection ?

If you try record classes in [`sharplab.io`](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQGMD2A3KCCWUAdjKkvAkcgD4ACATAIwCwAUG7QMwAESWCAE24AFBJgFx0MNgG823Bdy5LGABm4A5KAFsI3GdwDmEGAG5uyE+YC+8xcvwluAYVgRDmBAE8AkkIPGZhZW3LasYUA==) you'll see that record classes are usual classes that implement `IEquatable<T>` interface and contain additional members that are used to compare and clone instances of the record class. There is no special attributes that indicate that the class is a `record class`.

***So I guess that there is no way to determine if a class is a record class using reflection.***

> looking [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQGMD2A3KCCWUAdjKkvAkcgD4ACATAIwCwAUG7QMwAESWCAE24AFBJgFx0MNgG823Bdy5LGABm4A5KAFsI3GdwDmEGAG5uyE+YC+8xcvwluAYVgRDmBAE8AkkIPGZhZW3LasYUA==) maybe there is a way to detect the
> `EqualityContract` but I am not sure if that is the way to go ?

It is possible to determine using reflection if a class has such property, but this is not a 100% guarantee that the class with such property is a record class.

---

> 2. Is it possible to have a generic constraint that a generic type is a
>    record ? that is if it is possible to indicate that type parameter T
>    must be a record class using a constraint ?

It is not possible.

1. [Records proposal page](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-9.0/records.md) does not contain any information about specifying that a generic type parameter `T` must be a record class.
2. If you read discussion under this [comment](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/39#issuecomment-680312194) at `Champion records` page you'll learn that there is no way to specify something like `where T : record` in `C# 9`. Moreover there are plans to eliminate any meaningful semantic difference between a record and a class in `C# 10`. So that records' features like `with` will be available for classes too. Adding `record` constraint will make this goal not achievable.

Comment: thanks! 1- "So I believe that there is no way to determine if a class is a record class using reflection" - do you know where would be the right place to ask for a definite answer ? 2- yes I meant "if it is possible to indicate that type parameter T must be a record class" so I guess no

Comment: perhaps reflection can detect the EqualityContract ?

Comment: May be `csharplang` development team has additional information (or insights) about adding support of the features from questions #1 and #2. Therefore I think that better is to ask this question directly to `csharplang` team in [github repo of C#](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/new).

Comment: `perhaps reflection can detect the EqualityContract ?` It is possible to determine if a class has such property, but I don't think this is a 100% guarantee that the class with such property is a record class.

Answer (score 10):

As a 'hack', all records have a synthesized method `<Clone>$` which you can look for. Since you can't write a method with that name in C#, a class with a `<Clone>$` member is guaranteed to be a record **as of C# 9**.

However there is **no guarantee** that this will continue to be the case. For example it's possible that in C# 10.0 some records won't have a `<Clone>$` member, or that some non-records will.

```cs
public static bool IsRecord(Type type) => type.GetMethod("<Clone>$") != null;
```

Comment: I have no idea why would one do that but in theory with `Reflection.Emit` you could have someone create an object that has a `<Clone>$` method and that isn't a record

Comment: @nalka for sure, and you could also create such an object in a different language - but that's true of everything the compiler generates, even those with an 'official' way to check them.

Comment: To add just a little security to this, you could write: `public static bool IsRecord(Type type) => type.GetMethod("<Clone>$")?.ReturnType == type;`
That way another language could add a clone method to mimic a record, but it'd be fine... maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a very reasonable question to ask despite some of the answers here. The reality is that record is just syntactic sugar over a class and could be created a number of other ways.

One option would be the create an empty marker record base class or interface, even if empty and add the constraint to that. That will achieve the constraining required.

Provided you inherit from this classes for all the class you wish to include in the constraint then that will work fine.

Answer (score -2):

```
isRecord = t.GetMethod("<Clone>$") is object; ==> isRecord = t.GetMethod("<Clone>$") is not null;
```