# C# 9 records: how to specify a generic type T that must be a record

Tags: c#, generics, c#-9.0, record-classes

I am experimenting with the C# 9 RC, converting an existing application to use the new `record` construct and associated `with` keyword.

A high proportion  of my defined record types implement this interface (modified to use the `init` keyword instead of `set`):

```
public interface IHasModifiedDate
{
    DateTime ModifiedDate {get; init;}
}
```

(Note: the specific classes that implement this interface don't - and can't - have a common superclass).

I am trying to update a generic helper function that allows the modified date to be updated (where 'updated' *now* means: create a new instance with just that field change, using `with`) i.e.:

```
public static T UpdateModifiedDate<T>(T obj, DateTime whenTo) where T: IHasModifiedDate 
{
    return obj with {ModifiedDate = whenTo};
}
```

This gives the (reasonable) compile error: *The receiver type 'T' is not a valid record type*, and hence the `with` keyword cannot be used.

I would like to be able to add the constraint on T specifying that T is in fact a `record` (in the same way that you can specify that T must be a class) e.g:

```
public static T UpdateModifiedDate<T>(T obj, DateTime whenTo) where T: record, IHasModifiedDate 
{
    return obj with {ModifiedDate = when};
}
```

but the `record` keyword is not recognised in this context.

Is there any other way to specify that T is a record?

Comment: There is already a question that asks if it is possible to specify that a generic type is a record type: [c# 9.0 records - reflection and generic constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63097273/c-sharp-9-0-records-reflection-and-generic-constraints).

Comment: Records aren't a separate kind of type, they are still reference types with compile-type magic. There may be a proposal to add eg `where T:record` but that hasn't made it to C# 9.

Comment: Seems that C# team is not going to add an ability to specifty `where T : record` in `C# 9` (and future versions of `C#`). Read these comments [1](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/39#issuecomment-680312194), [2](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/39#issuecomment-680342093) in the discussion of `Records` (also read several following comments).

Comment: OK, I've posted on GitHub C# site -  as I think this is a huge constraint on the value of records.