# Is it possible to constrain a method for records only?

Tags: c#, generics, constraints, record

Let's assume I have several different `record`-types with a common interface, as follows:

```
record Rec1(
    string Tag
    ) : IFoo;

record Rec2(
    int Num,
    string Tag
    ) : IFoo;

record Rec3(
    bool Flag
    ) : IFoo
{
    public string Tag { get; init; }
    public double Value { get; init; }
}

// ... others ...

interface IFoo
{
    string Tag { get; }
}
```

My goal is to write a function to update the Tag property via record clonation.

Now, if the type were known, I could write something like this:

```
    private Rec2 Update(Rec2 rec, string tag)
    {
        return rec with { Tag = tag };
    }
```

However, I would avoid to write a bunch of overloads, so I'm wondering if there's a more generic way to achieve that. For instance, I'd tempted to write as:

```
    private TRec Update<TRec>(TRec rec, string tag) where TRec : IFoo
    {
        return rec with { Tag = tag };
    }
```

but that won't compile, because `TRec` could be anything (`class`, `struct`, etc), not just a `record` where I can use the `with` statement. By the way, there's no a `record`-constraint I could apply.

So, is there any workaround? is it anything to expect to be solved in the future?

As a bonus question (just for sake of curiosity), why a `record`-translated class isn't marked with a special interface, in order to make the `with` statement working against?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63097273/c-sharp-9-0-records-reflection-and-generic-constraints ?

Comment: @JohanDonne I even searched, but I did not find your post, so thanks. However, it doesn't actually answer to me: if they offer a "with" statement, able to work only with records, I believe they also should expose some kind of differentiation.

Comment: I agree, but at the moment they don't (afaik). A possible workaround can be found in the post I mentioned, in the answer by Rhexis: declaring an abstract record 'marker' class from which you derive all your records (tough you might get into trouble with multiple inheritance).

Comment: @JohanDonne I gave my own solution based on your hint. However, that's clearly a hack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of having an empty base record, have all these records inherit from a shared base record, that implements your interface:

```cs
record R : IFoo ...

record Rec1 : R....
record Rec2 : R....

private TRec Update<TRec>(TRec rec, string tag) where TRec : R
{
    return rec with { Tag = tag };
}
```

Comment: Agree, looks better!

Comment: IMHO, not only looks better but actually is better - not only you're not using a "marker" which is a code smell, you're actually using inheritance the way it should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to another answer (see link in the comments), it seems to be a hacky workaround:

```
record R();

record Rec1(
    string Tag
    ) : R, IFoo;

// ... others ...

interface IFoo
{
    string Tag { get; init; }
}

private TRec Update<TRec>(TRec rec, string tag) where TRec : R, IFoo
{
    return rec with { Tag = tag };
}
```

The constraint is effective due the `R` record, while the `Tag` assignment thanks to the `init` accessor.

Again, to me is much like a hack than a real solution. I'd prefer to see some native support.